# Connecting to JIRA using Plain JAVA APIs

Tags: jira-plugin

This is my first question ever in Stack-Overflow! 
I am beginner in JIRA. So I wanted to know if there is any stable platform to connect from Java to JIRA **without** using REST API?
Can I use native Java libraries or any other additional libraries to connect to JIRA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, atlassian created [jira-rest-java-client](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-rest-java-client) but doesn't "formally" support it...but is open source...last update was 2014-10-09...so seems maintained.

There is also the [SOAP services](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/SOAP+and+XML-RPC+API+Deprecated+in+JIRA+6.0), which are deprecated but still supported in JIRA 6.  They [provide instructions on how to build a SOAP client](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+JIRA+SOAP+Client). They'll be phased out, replaced by the REST endpoints, moving forward.

Comment: Yes, but it abstracts that away from you, so you're not using the REST API but rather a Java API.

Comment: Thank You! But the Doc for the API says , it's not stable , rather in Alpha Stage.

Comment: Yes, JIRAs REST API itself is Alpha as they're flushing that out right now.  I suppose I didn't initially understand your question.  You can still use their SOAP services, and they provide information on how to create a client.  REST will replace it, though.  Links will be added to answer.